# How to set up a pipenv from pipfile in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, pipenv

I have just downloaded a project where there is a pipfile. When I open it on pycharm it asks me if I want to create a pipenv, and asks for an executable. I created a pipenv already but I dont know which executable is it asking for, I already gave it the path where the pipenv was created.

[propmt I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFTIX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The executable it's asking for isn't in the pipenv environment, it's with the rest of your computer's binaries - usually near where your python executable is. If you installed your pipenv packages from the terminal, you can use

`which pipenv`

to find the executable's path. For example, on my computer it's at `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`.